# Prefix length with a value 0

Tags: networking, ipv6

In IPv6, the prefix length can range from 0-128. What is the significance of the prefix length with a value 0? Does it suggest that there is no network?

Thanks!

Comment: PS: @Maddy if someone answers your question it is polite to either accept the answer or comment on why the answer is not good enough...

Comment: @SanderSteffann: Thank you for your answer. I was out of office for a while and hence the delay.

Comment: you still haven't accepted the answer ;-)

Comment: Done :) I'm getting used to the process. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A prefix length of 0 (usually written as ::/0) means that no bits of the prefix are fixed and all 128 bits can be 0 or 1. So basically it includes all IPv6 addresses. This ranges from :: (same as 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000) to ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff.

When specifying the default route you define the route as ::/0 (every IPv6 address).